# jQuery filter divs with multiple attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have found great examples of simple filtering here, but couldn't figure out how to fix mine issue.

I have sidebar with elements

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="category" data-filter="A">Cat 1</div>
  <div class="category" data-filter="B">Cat 2</div>
  <div class="category" data-filter="A - 01">Cat 3</div>
  <div class="category" data-filter="B - 01">Cat 4</div>
</div>
```

And products

```
<div class="products">
  <div class="product" data-cat="A" data-f="A - 01">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product" data-cat="B" data-f="B - 01">Product 1</div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is to make a filter which will use [data-filter] attribute and show divs which have that attribute in [data-cat] or [data-f]. Is that possible?

This is the jQuery I've been using

```
<script>
    var $products = jQuery('.product');
jQuery('.category').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the category from the attribute
    var category = jQuery(this).data('filter');
       $products.hide().filter('[data-cat="]' + category + '"]').show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: values of `data-*` cannot have any spaces

Comment: Yes it's very possible, please post the jQuery that you tried using.

Comment: I would have two filters, one for data-cat and one for data-f. It would be similar to how filters work on MS Excel where you select the filters you want to hide/show.

Comment: Here's jQuery data I'm using `<script>
    var $products = jQuery('.product');
jQuery('.category').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the category from the attribute
    var category = jQuery(this).data('filter');
       $products.hide().filter('[data-cat="]' + category + '"]').show();
});
</script>`

Comment: My JSON API call pulls data and gives me such data with spaces. I can not change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector inside `filter` is incorrect, you'd need something like:

`.filter('[data-cat="' + category + '"], [data-f="' + category + '"]')`

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kwcotot/5/)

Comment: You're a life saver!